# One layout for 5 buttons

Tags: java, android, xml

I am doing a screen where I will have 5 buttons that are all going to be from other layout. That other layout is only the button defined. So when I call to initialize the first button and set its text like this:
    `Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.layout.layout_for_button);
          button.setText("text");` 
So it throws NullPointerException for the button. It's very strange and it does so on the first call of the button and I have to use that layout for 5 more.

Comment: what are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: Please post the full code with xml layout

Comment: well, I am doing a project and I have to make a screen with 5 buttons of the same type and I have defined a layout for button. I have to call make all buttons on the screen to be from this layout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting the `NullPointerException` because the `findViewById` does not find the button with an ID equal to the layout-Id. To find your button, you must do two things:

- In the Layout-XML give the button an unique id with `android:id="@+id/yourbutton"`. You get your button then with `findViewById(R.id.yourbutton)`
- Call the `findViewById` from within the right context. Usually the context is the `Activity` your're coding the `findViewById` in.

Answer (score 1):

you need to check for  `R.id` not `R.layout` inside findviewById

so do it this way

```
 Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonID);
 button.setText("text");
```

where **buttonID** is from layout xml for button  `android:id="@+id/buttonID"`

Answer (score 0):

**Android Basic Button Example:**

*res/layout/main.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button - Go to mkyong.com" />
 </LinearLayout>
```

*MyAndroidAppActivity.java*

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

public class MyAndroidAppActivity extends Activity {

    Button button;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

            // Do something

            }

        });

    } 
}
```

[Source](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-button-example/)

Answer (score -1):

This is quiet simple

```
Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.layout.layout_for_button); 
button.setText("text");
```

In your code above **button is null**

Something is wrong with `findViewById(R.layout.layout_for_button)`

May be your calling the **findViewById** from context

Comment: In Android, we find view using its id and syntax is:     

findViewById(R.id.view_id) and not findViewById(R.layout.layout_for_button);